# ggplot reordering variables specified in fill option

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am creating a barchart and in it im using fill to make distinction between 5 different variables. Here's the code:

```r
data <- suppressMessages(read_csv(csvpath))

# Changing the order of the data to suit better for Cumulative Flow Diagram
cfdLevels <- c("Backlog", "Selected for Development", "In Progress", "Closed", "Done")
data$status <- factor(data$status,levels = cfdLevels)
## Cumulative Flow Diagram ##
cumplot_pre <- ggplot(data, aes(x = currentdate, fill = status))
cumplot_pre + geom_bar(aes(y = ..count.., text = paste('Date: ', as.Date(currentdate), '\n',
                                                      'Status: ', status)))+
              ggtitle("Cumulative Flow Diagram")+
              theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+
              ylab("Count of Tickets")+
              scale_fill_manual(values = c("#2eb9d1", "#7f1dcf", "#fc3903", "#a6948f", "#fc9d03"))
```

And here is the graph:
[image]

What I am trying to achieve is that the status variables specified in fill-option would be in the order that im trying to re-order it in the code line 5 (starting with data$status) but i only achieve to re-order how its presented in the Legend.

How could I specify the order of these variables in the graph itself?

Edit to include dput:

```r
structure(list(currentdate = structure(c(18392, 18392, 18392, 
18392, 18392, 18392, 18392, 18392, 18392, 18392, 18392, 18392, 
18392, 18392, 18392, 18392, 18392, 18392, 18392, 18392, 18392, 
18392, 18392, 18392, 18392, 18392, 18392, 18392, 18392, 18392, 
18392, 18392, 18392, 18392, 18392, 18392, 18392, 18392, 18392, 
18406, 18406, 18377, 18377, 18377, 18377, 18377, 18377, 18390, 
18390, 18390, 18390, 18390, 18390, 18390, 18390, 18390, 18390, 
18390, 18390, 18390, 18390, 18390, 18390, 18390, 18390, 18390, 
18390, 18390, 18390, 18390, 18390, 18390, 18390, 18390, 18390, 
18390, 18390, 18390, 18390, 18406, 18406, 18406, 18406, 18406, 
18406, 18406, 18406, 18406, 18406, 18406, 18377, 18406, 18406, 
18406, 18406, 18389, 18389, 18389, 18389, 18389), class = "Date"), 
    status = structure(c(1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
    5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 
    1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    1L), .Label = c("Backlog", "Selected for Development", "In Progress", 
    "Closed", "Done"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks for reply but atleast as is, it didnt work. It didnt change the graph in any way.

Comment: @AllanCameron I added the dput. I filtered it down to only the 2 values used in the graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be best to plot a summarised table based on grouped counts. That way the stacked values appear in the same order as the legend colours:

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(currentdate, status) %>% 
  summarise(count = length(status)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = currentdate, y = count, fill = status)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack()) +
  ggtitle("Cumulative Flow Diagram")+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+
  ylab("Count of Tickets")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#2eb9d1", "#7f1dcf", "#fc3903", 
                               "#a6948f", "#fc9d03"))
```

[image]